# tkinter.Text widget method dump add parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, text-widget

this is content of help about Text widget method from python/IDLE named: dump

```
 |  dump(self, index1, index2=None, command=None, **kw)
 |      Return the contents of the widget between index1 and index2.
 |      
 |      The type of contents returned in filtered based on the keyword
 |      parameters; if 'all', 'image', 'mark', 'tag', 'text', or 'window' are
 |      given and true, then the corresponding items are returned. The result
 |      is a list of triples of the form (key, value, index). If none of the
 |      keywords are true then 'all' is used by default.
 |      
 |      If the 'command' argument is given, it is called once for each element
 |      of the list of triples, with the values of each triple serving as the
 |      arguments to the function. In this case the list is not returned.
```

I can only make this work (below). No idea how to add parameters to it. I mean 'mark', 'tag', 'text' etc.

```
myText.dump("sel.first","sel.last"):
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add parameters by setting keyword arguments named after those parameters to `True`. It says this right in the documentation (with emphasis added by me):

> The type of contents returned in filtered based on the **keyword
> parameters**; if 'all', 'image', 'mark', 'tag', 'text', or 'window' **are given and true**, then the corresponding items are returned.

For example, to set the `tag` parameter you would do it like this:

```
text.dump("1.0", "end", tag=True)
```

Similarly, to get tag and text information you would do this:

```
text.dump("1.0", "end", tag=True, text=True)
```

Comment: how to import them back to the text widget?